# About the basis for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I know that the sets of all open balls with rational radius and center form a basis for usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. That is,
$$
B = \{I \subset \mathbb{R} \mid \exists a,b\in \mathbb{Q}:a<b \land I = (a,b)\}
$$
is a basis.

Then, can we think of a proper subset of $B$ that forms a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sure. Delete the intervals with $0$ as  a left end-point, for example. Or just delete any one interval from $B$.

Comment: Here's another one: Given any $\varepsilon>0$, delete all $(a,b)$ with $b-a\ge \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ then

$$B'=\{(a,b)\ |\ a,b\in D\}$$

will be a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ and a subset of $B$. Proper if $D$ is proper.

This gives us lots of examples, infinitely many in fact. You can remove a single point from $\mathbb{Q}$ or even consider $D_k=\{n/k^m\ |n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for a fixed natural $k\in\mathbb{N}$.